# ARM template to create storage account with both blob and table

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-rm-template

Is it possible to create an Azure Storage Account with a blob container and a table storage via ***ARM template***? I see examples of creating storage account & blob container (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/2019-04-01/storageaccounts) but not both blob and table. Please provide some useful documentations.

What changes are required in the following code to create both blob and table:

```
"resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "name": "[parameters('name')]",
      "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",      
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "kind": "StorageV2",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('sku')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true
      },
      "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain tables creation is not yet supported. blob\files are.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/